# Does there exist a recurrence relation which cannot be written in a closed form?

Tags: recurrences

I'm looking for an example of a recurrence relation where it provably does not have a closed form.

Does such a thing exist?

For example, I believe $S(n, k)$, or the Stirling numbers of the second type, do not have a closed form -- but I'm not sure if they *don't* or if they *can't*.

Comment: Because there are sequences with no closed form, there are a fortiori recurrence relations with no closed form.  Let $a_0=0$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}$ plus the number of solutions to the $n$th entry on some complete list of diophantine equations.  Or do you mean to require a "closed form" for $a_{n+1}-a_n$?   What counts as a recurrence relation?  And what counts as a closed form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure you're aware that linear recurrent sequences are well understood and can be solved exactly by a "closed formula". Once you enter the world of non-linear recurrences, even when restricting to constant coefficients, you can get all sorts of strange behavior even with some very simple looking recurrences. One example is the [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map):
$$x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n)$$
which is only exactly solvable for a few special values of the constant $r$. For the complex and chaotic behavior that happens with other values of $r$ you can check the wiki article, which has a nice bifurcation diagram and summary of the qualitative properties of this map.